# Can we know the electric field from polarization when we don't know the susceptibility?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, polarization

So, one of my textbook problems reads-

> A dielectric sphere has polarisation $\textbf{P}=\beta \ \hat{r}$ and has a radius $R$. What is the potential difference between the centre and the surface?

My approach- Since we know that $P=\epsilon_o \chi E$, the electric field, thus also points radially outwards and is given by-
$$E=\dfrac{\beta}{\chi \epsilon_o} \hat{r}$$
From where we find the answer which should be given by $\dfrac{\beta R}{\chi \epsilon_o}$

Now, the textbook claims that the answer to this problem is-

$$V=\dfrac{-\beta R}{\epsilon_o}$$ which I honestly think is a typo, but still wanted to clarify.

1. Where did their $\chi$ go? Is it a convention to assume it as $1$ when it's not mentioned?
2. Obviously the $-$ sign is wrong in equation above right? Since we will have to do positive work to reach the centre.
3. The most important question- Did they take an altogether different method in which they didn't even need $\chi$ for the solution, which is the title of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can figure out the charge without knowing the susceptibility quite easily, since the bound charge density is $\rho_b = - \mathbf{\nabla \cdot P}$.  By calculating $\rho_b$, we can then find the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ created by the bound charge, and then the potential difference.  Note that since $\rho_b$ is fairly obviously negative in this case, a negative final answer is quite plausible.

Your method implicitly assumes that the electric displacement field, $
\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}$, is non-zero.  In particular, it works out that under your assumptions,
$$
\mathbf{D} = \frac{\epsilon_r}{\chi_e} \mathbf{P},
$$
and so $\rho_f = \mathbf{\nabla \cdot D} \neq 0$.  In other words, to create the electric fields you've assumed, there has to be some free charge present, which is not mentioned in the problem.